# Does crypt Command Unix/Solaris 10 support 128bit encryption/decryption?

Tags: unix, encryption, command, solaris

I need to know whether the "crypt" Command Unix/Solaris 10 support 128bit encryption/decryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Blog Post](http://blogs.oracle.com/darren/entry/encrypting_files_in_solaris_10) shows that crypt on Solaris 10 does not use anything like DES, RSA, AES etc (wich are typically involved when speaking of "128 Bit encryption"). It uses a weak function that can be broken by many tools, one mentioned in that very article. Use the openssl library or tools when you need up-to-date cryptography.

Answer (score 2):

Use the encrypt and decrypt commands which are always installed on Solaris 10. Openssl provides similar functionalities but might be missing from a standard installation.